# Prevent Store from Showing in Redux Dev Tools

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm using Chrome Redux Dev Tools to help debug my react app's Redux store. I added a new dependency, [`react-beautiful-dnd`](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd), which apparently uses redux, because now instead of my single store showing up in Chrome Redux Dev Tools, I also see stores for React Beautiful dnd.

I'd prefer not to see these at all, because now every time I want to go to my store, I have to manually select it from a list.

Is their anyway to keep `react-beautiful-dnd` as a dependency in my project, but prevent it from showing up in Chrome Redux Dev Tools?

Perhaps there's some kind of config file that controls the visibility of the store? Or a setting within Redux Dev Tools that controls which stores are visible?

What Chrome Redux Dev Tools currently looks like for me:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can do this, certainly with EasyPeasy, which I assume means you could do it with Redux. EasyPeasy provides a `devTools` prop for `EasyPeasyConfig`:

```js
const store = createStore(model, {devTools: false});
store.addModel('todos', {
  items: ['Buy shoes'],
});
store.getState().todos.items; // ["Buy shoes"]
```

[As per the Store Config docs](https://easy-peasy.vercel.app/docs/api/store-config.html), if `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'` then by default `devTools = true`.

The store no longer appear if `devTools = false`.

But I'm still not sure how to disable a store which is in a dependency.